# gcloud crashed (TransportError)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

From last two weeks getting gcloud crashed error for my Wifi- Tikona. But when I connected to mobile hot (Airtel) spot then it is getting connected. How to resolve this error?

> gcloud crashed (TransportError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa4cf786610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))